# Lua Copas, help clarifying how to handle multiple users

Tags: scope, lua

I'm a bit confused and think it's going to be an easy answer but my searches aren't helping me much :(  I want to be able to do an skt:send anywhere.  I could send it into OutToUser function as a parameter but I'm going to have a lot of different places I'll want to do this at and feel that will get too messy.  I tried storing it something like Server.connections[key] = skt where key is host and port but can't figure out how to get host and port again later when I need it.

Any good solutions?

*edit* I get that it's a scope issue but not seeing a good solution as I'm new to lua.

```
require "copas"
Server = {}
function Server:new()
    local object = {}
    setmetatable(object, { __index = Server })
    return object
end

function Server:init()
    function handler(skt, host, port)
        while true do
            data = skt:receive()
            if data == "quit" then
                -- isn't going to work
                OutToUser(data)

                -- this would work fine of course
                -- skt:send(data .. "\r\n")
            end
        end
    end

    server = socket.bind("*", 49796)
    copas.addserver(server, 
        function(c) return handler(copas.wrap(c), c:getpeername()) end
    )
    copas.loop()
end

function OutToUser(data)
    skt:send(data .. "\r\n")
end

server = Server:new()
server:init()
```

Comment: Where else are you going to need to pass skt to OutToUser?

Comment: I'm moreso trying to figure out how to be able to determine which user is doing something without having to pass around skt.  So for example, instead of OutToUser, what I'm really doing is something like "determineResponse", which then takes the user input and determines what to do with it - maybe echo something back to user, or jump to another class's method and save something, or etc.  I tried to keep it simple in this example though and figure out how to access skt in OutToUser without having to pass it in as a parameter.  It can't be a single global var though because of multiple users.

Comment: See my answer for two possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define OutToUser in the scope of the handler:

```
function Server:init()
    local function handler(skt, host, port)

        --make the function local to here
        local function OutToUser(data)
            --references the skt variable in the enclosing scope
            --(the handler function)
            skt:send(data .. "\r\n")
        end

        while true do
            data = skt:receive()
            if data == "quit" then
                OutToUser(data)
            end
        end
    end

    local server = socket.bind("*", 49796)
    copas.addserver(server, 
        function(c) return handler(copas.wrap(c), c:getpeername()) end
    )
    copas.loop()
end
```

Functions can always reference variables in their scope (function arguments and variables declared with `local`), even once they've left that scope - you can use that as an alternative solution, where you *enclose* the variables you want the function to use in a scope outside the function:

```
local function makeOTU(skt)

    --skt is visible in the scope of the function
    --that gets returned as a result

    return function(data)
        skt:send(data .. "\r\n")
    end
end

function Server:init()
    local function handler(skt, host, port)

    --create a function that references skt
    --as part of its closure
    local OutToUser = makeOTU(skt)

        while true do
            data = skt:receive()
            if data == "quit" then
                -- OutToUser is still referencing the
                -- skt from the call to makeOTU()
                OutToUser(data)
            end
        end
    end

    local server = socket.bind("*", 49796)
    copas.addserver(server, 
        function(c) return handler(copas.wrap(c), c:getpeername()) end
    )
    copas.loop()
end
```

Note the use of the `local` keyword in both of these examples: if you neglect the `local`, the name will ignore the scope altogether and go into / come from [the global environment](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.html) (which is just a table like any other: when you invoke a new Lua state, it's placed in the global `_G`), which is not what you want.

Keeping your variables local to their scope instead of using globals is important. Take, for example, these two functions:

```
local function yakkity(file, message)

    line = message .. '\n' --without local,
                           --equivalent to _G["line"] = message

    function yak() --without local,
                   --equivalent to _G["yak"] = function()

        file:write(line) --since no local "line" is defined above,
                         --equivalent to file:write(_G["line"])
    end
    for i=1, 5 do
        yak()
    end
end

local function yakker(file, message)
    line = message .. '\n' --without local,
                           --equivalent to _G["line"] = message

    return function()
        file:write(line) --again, since no local "line" is defined above,
                         --equivalent to file:write(_G["line"])
    end
end
```

Because their variables aren't defined as local, they clobber each other's data, leave their belongings lying around where anybody can abuse them, and just generally act like slobs:

```
--open handles for two files we want:
local yesfile = io.open ("yesyes.txt","w")
local nofile = io.open ("no.txt","w")

--get a function to print "yes!" - or, rather,
--print the value of _G["line"], which we've defined to "yes!".
--We'll see how long that lasts...
local write_yes = yakker(yesfile,"yes!")

--Calling write_yes() now will write "yes!" to our file.
write_yes()

--when we call yakkity, though, it redefines the global value of "line"
--(_G["line"]) - as well as defining its yak() function globally!
--So, while this function call does its job...
yakkity(nofile, "oh no!")

--calling write_yes(), which once again looks up the value of _G["line"],
--now does the exact OPPOSITE of what it's supposed to-
write_yes() --this writes "oh no!" to yesfile!

--additionally, we can still write to the nofile handle we passed to yakkity()
--by calling the globally-defined yak() function!
yak() --this writes a sixth "oh no!" to nofile!

--even once we're done with the file and close our handle to it...
nofile:close()

--yak() still refers to that handle and will still try to write to it!
yak() --tries to write to the closed file handle and throws an error!
```

Comment: Scope stuff in lua is proving to be the most difficult part!  Your answer made me rethink how to approach the issue and after messing around with your code and incorporating it into mine, I figured out what I needed to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is have the `OutToUser` function also accept the skt argument, and pass it along from inside the handler.

Comment: That works, but my goal here is to be able to determine which user is doing something in any function *without* passing the socket in as a parameter (because it's going to get messy passing it around everywhere).